# R - Concatenate string elements based on another array

Tags: arrays, r, string, concatenation

I have a simple issue and I found a very complicated (C stylish) solution and I am wondering if there is something much simpler than this.
I have two arrays:

```
  y <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
  d <- c(1,3,1)
```

and I need to get an array as

```
"A","B-C-D","E"
```

so based on the distribution `d`, aggregate the elements of `y` separated by a `-` (or any other separator).

I did this

```
old_y <- y
y <- NULL

k <- 1
for (i in 1:length(d)) {
  y[i] <- as.character(old_y[k])
  j <- 1
  while(d[i]>j) {
    y[i] <- paste0(y[i], "-", as.character(old_y[k+j]))
    j <- j + 1
  }
  k <- k + d[i]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `tapply` on 'y' grouped by the sequence of 'd' replicated by 'd' and `paste` the elements of 'y' together.

```
unname(tapply(y, rep(seq_along(d), d), FUN = paste, collapse="-"))
#[1] "A"     "B-C-D" "E"
```